# How to transform 64 bit string into hex?

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to convert 64 bit zigbee address into its equivalent hex address. I have gone through many post but could not find any solution. I have 64 bit address in string format and I want it into its equivalent hex.

For example, I have

`unsigned char ZbAddStr[16] = "0013A20040B5A5EE"`

and I want to convert it into

`unsigned char ZbAddNew[8] = {0x00, 0x13, 0xA2, 0x00, 0x40, 0xB5, 0xA5, 0xEE}`.

How can I do this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy two bytes of `ZbAddStr` to a temporary string.
2. Use `strtol` to extract the number out of those two bytes using 16 as the base.
3. Save the number to `ZbAddNew`.

This should work:

```
char temp[3] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 2 )
{
   temp[0] =  ZbAddStr[i];
   temp[1] =  ZbAddStr[i+1];
   int num = strtol(temp, NULL, 16);
   ZbAddNew[i/2] = num;
}
```

This should also work (Thanks @JonathanLeffler):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
{
   sscanf((char*)&ZbAddStr[2*i], "%2X", &ZbAddNum[i]);
}
```

Comment: Would there be any major disadvantage to using `sscanf()`, possibly with a monster format string `"%2X%2X…%2X%2X"` and 8 addresses, or in a loop `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) sscanf(&ZbAddStr[2*i], "%2X", &ZbAddNew[i]);`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I didn't try the first suggestion but the second one works for me. I don't see any major pros/cons, subtle or otherwise, between the two approaches.

Comment: @CoolNik, good for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answers..

I have achieved it using following code.. It does not call any standard function.

Code link : http://goo.gl/GwXH3x